# Exchange 2003 very reliant of 1 on 4 AD servers, Freezes without it

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook

On-site we have 3 of 4 AD servers (AD1,AD2 and AD4) with AD1 having most of the Operational Master Roles, however when AD2 goes down, freezes or reboots outlook says 'waiting for exchange server AD2', when exchange is on a different box completely.
AD4 was just built from scratch and added hoping to get around this reliance on AD2 but it doesn't seem to have any effect, had a look through exchange settings and couldn't find any locations it points to AD2 and no other active directory servers.

Would appreciate some help on the matter,
Thank You

Comment: Which of your AD servers have a copy of the Global Catalog?

Comment: Have you checked on the Directory Access tab of the server properties to see which DC's Exchange is using?

Comment: All Servers are Global Catalogue, not just AD2 and DA Tab shows all 4 servers for everything, AD2 for Configuration Master (I believe this changes by itself, its set to auto)

Comment: Ditto joeqwerty.  You don't mention whether are in the same AD site (I appreciate they're in the same physical site).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run this on exchange server.

start > run > cmd

```
nltest /dsgetdc:DOMAIN_NAME /GC
nltest /dclist:DOMAIN_NAME
```

Also, does AD2 hold your DNS ? do you have a backup DNS ?

If AD2 holds DNS and GC roles, and AD2 goes down, even if you have other AD's configured as GC, outlook clients will have issues connecting to Exchange Server.

If you have more than one DC+GC, and you are still facing the problem, restart Exchange System Attendant service and check if outlook users are able to connect.